# React Navigation 5.x stack navigation show blank screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation-stack

//app.js  "react": "16.9.0","react-native": "0.61.5", offic
follow the official document but show blank screen react native

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './App/redux/store/store'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AppSplashScreen from './App/screens/splashScreen/SplashScreen';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


function MyStack() {
 return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={AppSplashScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {}
   }

   render() {
        return (
                <>
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                  <SafeAreaView  >
                    <Provider store={configureStore()} >
                      <NavigationContainer>
                        <MyStack />
                      </NavigationContainer>
                    </Provider>
                 </SafeAreaView>
                </>
               );
             }

           };
```

but replace  MyStack to AppSplashScreen then show SplashScreen

Comment: it had to do with safe area context not react navigation itself

Answer (score 18):

Solved by adding `style={{flex: 1}}` to the SafeAreaView.

```
    const App = () => {   
        return (
           <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
             <NavigationContainer>
               <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                 <Stack.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{title: 'Overview'}}
                 />
               </Stack.Navigator>
             </NavigationContainer>
          </SafeAreaView>   
    )};
```

Comment: I got it to work! But whyyyyy ? Whyyyy on SafeAreaView ????

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine, try not to separate the Stack.Navigator from the navigation container

this works for me

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Homepage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Notes" component={Notes} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
   </Provider>
 );
}
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

You should set `SafeAreaView` height to 100%.
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'; const screenStack = createStackNavigator(); const Navigation = () => { return ( <SafeAreaView style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>  <screenStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"> <screenStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{title: 'Welcome'}} /> </screenStack.Navigator>   ); }; export default Navigation;

Comment: Please provide the **code** to achieve this.

Comment: import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

const screenStack = createStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        
        <screenStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <screenStack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{title: 'Welcome'}}
          />
        </screenStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Navigation;

Comment: please [edit] the answer with this